# functions inside NotifierProvider class have many errors

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a povider class that I am working on converting to riverpod 2.0. I have defined the User class which is the data model and the NotifierProvider class below. Inside the NotifierProvider class, I have a function, saveUser(), that populates a variable newUser depending if data is new or it has been retrieved from the db. The notifierProvider class is of the User type.

```
class Users {
  String? userId;
  String? fName;
  String? lName;
  String? address1;
  String? address2;
  String? city;
  String? state;
  String? zipCode;
  String? cellPhone;
  String? officePhone;
  String? email;
  String? company;
  String? mls;

  Users(
      {this.userId,
      this.fName,
      this.lName,
      this.address1,
      this.address2,
      this.city,
      this.state,
      this.zipCode,
      this.cellPhone,
      this.officePhone,
      this.email,
      this.company,
      this.mls});

  Users copyWith({
    String? userId,
    String? fName,
    String? lName,
    String? address1,
    String? address2,
    String? city,
    String? state,
    String? zipCode,
    String? cellPhone,
    String? officePhone,
    String? email,
    String? company,
    String? mls,
  }) {
    return Users(
      fName: fName ?? this.fName,
      lName: lName ?? this.lName,
      address1: address1 ?? this.address1,
      address2: address2 ?? this.address2,
      city: city ?? this.city,
      state: state ?? this.state,
      zipCode: zipCode ?? this.zipCode,
      cellPhone: cellPhone ?? this.cellPhone,
      officePhone: officePhone ?? this.officePhone,
      email: email ?? this.email,
      company: company ?? this.company,
      mls: mls ?? this.mls,
    );
  }
}
```

The NotifierProvider class is of the type Users which is the class above. So, since I have declared the class as a User class why do I get "undefined" errors on all of the data elements in the UsersNotifier class? Shouldn't they be declared because of the type declaration of the Notifier class?

If I hover over the Users where I extends Notifier a popup shows I am using the "Class Users" from the user_provider.dart file which is the same file the NotifierClass is located.

```
class UsersNotifier extends Notifier<Users> {
  final firestoreService = FirestoreService();
  final companyRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(('Company'));
  final userRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(('users'));

// **************************************************

  @override
  Users build() {
    return Users(
      userId: '',
      fName: '',
      lName: '',
      address1: '',
      address2: '',
      city: '',
      state: '',
      zipCode: '',
      cellPhone: '',
      officePhone: '',
      email: '',
      company: '',
      mls: '',
    );
  }

  // functions to update class members
  void updatefName(String newfName) {
    state = state.copyWith(fName: newfName);
  }

  void updatelName(String newlName) {
    state = state.copyWith(lName: newlName);
  }

  void updateaddress1(String newaddress1) {
    state = state.copyWith(address1: newaddress1);
  }

  void updateaddress2(String newaddress2) {
    state = state.copyWith(address2: newaddress2);
  }

  void updateCity(String newCity) {
    state = state.copyWith(city: newCity);
  }

  void updateState(String newState) {
    state = state.copyWith(state: newState);
  }

  void updateZipcode(String newZipcode) {
    state = state.copyWith(zipCode: newZipcode);
  }

  void updateCellPhone(String newCellPhone) {
    state = state.copyWith(cellPhone: newCellPhone);
  }

  void updateOfficePhone(String newOfficePhone) {
    state = state.copyWith(officePhone: newOfficePhone);
  }

  void updateEmail(String newEmail) {
    state = state.copyWith(email: newEmail);
  }

  void updateCompany(String newCompany) {
    state = state.copyWith(company: newCompany);
  }

  void updateMls(String newMls) {
    state = state.copyWith(mls: newMls);
  }

// **************************************************

  saveUser(ref) async {

    if (ref.watch(globalsNotifierProvider).newUser == true) {
      final DocumentSnapshot currentCompanyProfile =
      await companyRef.doc(ref.watch(globalsNotifierProvider).companyId).get();

      var newUser = Users(
          userId: ref.watch(globalsNotifierProvider).currentUserId,
          fName: fName,  <<<  undefined name 'fName'
          lName: lName,  <<<  undefined name 'fLame'
          mls: mls,  <<<  undefined name 'mls'
          mlsId: ref.watch(globalsNotifierProvider).mlsId,
          address1: currentCompanyProfile.get('address1'),
          address2: currentCompanyProfile.get('address2'),
          city: currentCompanyProfile.get('city'),
          state: currentCompanyProfile.get('state'),
          zipcode: currentCompanyProfile.get('zipCode'),
          cellPhone: currentCompanyProfile.get('cellPhone'),
          officePhone: currentCompanyProfile.get('officePhone'),
          companyId: ref.watch(globalsNotifierProvider).companyId;
          company: company),  <<<  undefined name 'company'
      firestoreService.saveUser(newUser, ref);
      ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier).updatenewUser(false);
    } else {
      final DocumentSnapshot currentuserProfile =
        await userRef.doc(ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).currentuserId).get();

      var newUser = Users(
          userId: ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).currentUid,
          fName:
              (fName != null && fName != "") ? fName : currentuserProfile.get('fName'),
          lName:
              (lName != null && lName != "") ? lName : currentuserProfile.get('lName'),
          address1: (address1 != null && address1 != "")
              ? address1
              : currentuserProfile.get('address1'),
          address2: (address2 != null && address2 != "")
              ? address2
              : currentuserProfile.get('address2'),
          city: (city != null && city != "") ? city : currentuserProfile.get('city'),
          state:  (state != null && state != "") ? state : currentuserProfile.get('state'),
          /*state: (globals.selectedState != null)
              ? globals.selectedState
              : globals.currentuserState,*/
          zipcode: (zipCode != null && zipCode != "")
              ? zipCode
              : currentuserProfile.get('zipCode'),
          cellPhone: (cellPhone != null && cellPhone != "")
              ? cellPhone
              : currentuserProfile.get('cellPhone'),
          officePhone: (officePhone != null && officePhone != "")
              ? officePhone
              : currentuserProfile.get('officePhone'),
          companyId: ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).CompanyId,
          company: (company != null && company != "")
              ? company
              : currentuserProfile.get('Company'),
          mlsId: ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).mlsId,
          mls: (mls != null && mls != "")
              ? mls
              : currentuserProfile.get('mls'));
      firestoreService.saveUser(newUser, ref);
    }
  }

  deleteUser(String? userId) {
    firestoreService.deleteUser(userId);
  }
}

final usersNotifierProvider = NotifierProvider<UsersNotifier, Users>(() {
  return UsersNotifier();
});
```

In the NotifierProvider class I am getting a lot of undefined variables and some of the named parameters are saying they are undefined.

In the var newUser = User( code all of the variables are undefined. I think it may have something to do with the first line where I am assigning a global variable from the globalsNotifierProvider:

```
userId: ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).currentUid,
```

The "else" statement is where I am getting most of the errors. Every variable is undefined.

Can I get help on why this is happening? I know it is going to be something simple but I just don't see it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The class `UsersNotifier` is not extending `Users` and the errors are quite accurate, *you don't have `x` in `this`*. This is because a class can't extend or implement generics (the `T`).

Usually the ide will give you a warning that you can't do something but when you use dynamic and/or null-able variables the ide can't know for sure if you are doing some casting magic or a mistake.

This example is not a one to one to what `Notifier` is doing but it has the same error and you should keep in mind that you may not be able to access it if it's a private variable (`_generic`).

```dart
class Class {
  String name = 'my_class';
}

class Notifier<T> {
  final T generic;
  Notifier(this.generic);
}

class MyNotifier extends Notifier<Class> {
  MyNotifier() : super(Class());

  void print_name() {
    // print(this.name); // Error
    print(this.generic.name);
  }
}

void main() {
  var instance = MyNotifier();
  instance.print_name();
}
```

As described in the [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/Notifier-class.html) `state` is the `generic` from my example. If you want more details on what it's doing or how just check the inheritance line from the [class](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/blob/master/packages/riverpod/lib/src/notifier/base.dart#L75C19-L75C19).

In short, instead of `fName` use `state.fName` and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am new to flutter so let me see if I understand. This is what I did but I get an error on super(Users());  class UsersNotifier extends Notifier<Users> {
  UsersNotifier() : super(Users());

Comment: You can't just super anything, it needs to match the constructor and `Notifier` doesn't have one, but it has a `build()` method that you implement and must constructs the `User` , meaning that what you return in it it's what you get in the `state`; see the end of the answer.